# What does the ISAVEPERCENT variable do in AutoCad?

Tags: autocad, cad, autodesk, autocad-plugin, autolisp

Currently, my save times can vary from 10 seconds to 3 minutes depending on the size of the file I am working on. Therefore, I have been attempting to decrease the save time for larger files for myself and others at my company and I came across the variable: `ISAVEPERCENT`. After asking questions in other forums and looking for similar posts, I have only been given the response that is much like [this one](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-469DFA87-1986-4BDA-918B-1E3F9D6FCDC2).

Before I implement any variable changes for everyone at my company, I want to know exactly what this variable does (I.E. does it save some kind of meta data to the .dwg file increasing the save time or does it actually use the ac$ in some way?)

I found a possible answer [here](http://blogs.rand.com/support/2012/12/what-in-the-world-is-isavepercent.html) but this sounds like the exact opposite of what is said in AutoCAD's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in essence the difference between qsave (quick save)  and Save (full save).  If Isavepercent is at 50 the qsave command saves changes to the dwq by "Appending" it to the database.  Ones the wasted space is at 50% the next save will be a Full save.

This used to be necessary with slow performance issues of hard drives etc.

But in this time of SSD and fast storage, the speed difference between "save" and "qsave" is negligible, so I always set it to 0.

Comment: I work off of a network with speed tests yielding 25 MB/s write speeds and 80 MB/s, roughly tenth of the speed of an SSD thus your assumption would be incorrect. 

Do you have any estimates or information regarding the increases in speed it would provide? Furthermore, where does it save the "database" that information is appended to?